Waiting time in an intersection
I'm trying to track average waiting time of vehicles in a traffic light, I've made a parameter queueEntryTime which defaults to time() in the Sedan agent:

I want to access this parameter in Main like so:

double waitingTime = time() - Sedan.queueEntryTime; 
vehicleWaitingTimeStats.add(waitingTime);

so I can add the value into the available statistics when the car passed the intersection.
but I always get this error:
Description: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field Sedan.queueEntryTime. Location: Model7/Main/level/roadNetwork/roadDewiSartikaBarat/stopLineDSBarat - Stop Line
I've tried to make queueEntryTime as a variable instead of a parameter but I still get the same error. I don't know what to do.

you didnt provide the code that is giving you that error

@DerekRoberts Sorry, it was only in the screenshot, I've edited the post now...

probably car.queueEntryTime instead of Sedan.queueEntryTime -- Please check this question and its answer: Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?

@user85421 I get this error when I do that:
Description: queueEntryTime cannot be resolved or is not a field.
I uploaded the image since it's using GUI for the coding itself, I don't want people to get confused with what I am talking about.

( or maybe ((Sedan) car).queueEntryTime) based on un-posted code -- but without knowing how queueEntryTime is declared, this is just a (Java based) guess; but I also believe that the posted code should be part of the un-posted if block ) -- it is OK to upload (some) images; but code must also be included as TEXT

No need to double post here and on LinkedIn. Check this guide to decide which one to use: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-community

And only use the AnyLogic tag, else you confuse thousands of other SOF users that expect this to be a pure java problem (they don't know AnyLogic)

The Java solution, assuming that queueEntryTime is a field of Sedan, would be something like:
if (car instanceof Sedan) {
    carDewiSartikaBarat--;
    Sedan sedan = (Sedan) car;
    double waitingTime = time() - sedan.queueEntryTime; 
    vehicleWaitingTimeStats.add(waitingTime);
}

but I do not know how Sedan  and car are declared.
